# How to get names of function use in code

Tags: c++, parsing

I get body of C++ method as String and want to get list of all methods that were used in this code.
What tool will be best to do such parsing?

It must support all situation:

```
opSomeMethod();
someObject.someMethod();
someObject->someMethod();
```

Best if it will be in Java but it could be little c++ program that work from console.

Comment: A C++ compiler leaps to mind.

Comment: Clang is probably your best bet although you could go full on and use one of the C++ grammars for ANTLR or any of the other parser generators.

Comment: WhozCraig: It seems little complicated, could you show me which compiler leaps you mean with simple example?

@Captain Obvlious: Could you point me to some example, i try to find the easiest and clean way to get those functions name from fragment of code?

Comment: I have to go with Captain on this. It probably offers the best chance at picking up symbols correctly. Even then some of them will be near-impossible to fully calculate. esp in the case where obj.mthd() is actually firing void \*(mthd)(), a member *variable* of obj's class that happens to also be a function pointer.

Comment: You actually need a full C++ front-end to do it correctly in all possible situations. Parsers *are not enough*.

Comment: @Jack - One big problem is that the code might contain `#define someMethod someOtherMethod`. To solve that, you need a full front-end.

Comment: I can assume that this `#define someMethod someOtherMethod` situation never happens.

Comment: @Jack Here is a [tutorial](http://amnoid.de/tmp/clangtut/tut.html) for parsing C files which can be applied to C++ with a few minor tweaks. It includes example code as well as test files and additional information that maybe useful to you.

Comment: @ybungalobill I disagree. All the OP needs is a dump of all typenames used in their project. A parser with symbol table support and the ability to handle both templates and expressions (think about the usage of '>') will suffice. That's a far cry from having a full blown C++ front end. Take a look at the C++ grammars for ANTLR 2.7 and 3.x.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: the op needs *methods*, not *typenames*. For example in the above code what `someObject->someMethod();` means? It depends on the type of `someObject` which may overload `->` in which case `someMethod` may be a method of some `class T`, which also may be defined in the base class of `T` and may have been overloaded, templatized, etc etc...

Comment: @Jack: what you expect to be the output from the sample code you shown?

Comment: Thanks for tutorial I will check it. The result I want from above is list of method names:`opSomeMethod;someMethod;someMethod`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LEX and the YACC tools for defining the grammar and for parsing the string.
Lex and Yacc can read the source program and discover its structure.

The task of discovering the source structure again is decomposed into subtasks:

- Split the source file into tokens (Lex).
- Find the hierarchical structure of the program (Yacc).

Lex helps write programs whose control flow is directed by instances of regular expressions in the input stream. It is well suited for editor-script type transformations and for segmenting input in preparation for a parsing routine. Lex source is a table of regular expressions and corresponding program fragments. The table is translated to a program which reads an input stream, copying it to an output stream and partitioning the input into strings which match the given expressions. As each such string is recognized the corresponding program fragment is executed. The recognition of the expressions is performed by a deterministic finite automaton generated by Lex. The program fragments written by the user are executed in the order in which the corresponding regular expressions occur in the input stream.

[See the online manual for LEX for more details](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/lex/index.html).

Yacc provides a general tool for describing the input to a computer program. The Yacc user specifies the structures of his input, together with code to be invoked as each such structure is recognized. Yacc turns such a specification into a subroutine that han- dles the input process; frequently, it is convenient and appropriate to have most of the flow of control in the user's application handled by this subroutine.

[See the online manual for YACC for more details](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/yacc/index.html).